# Comparing tables information to retrieve from another

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am really stuck on this one problem. I need to create a query in which I have a table that holds the CustomerID and a PurchaseID number. In another table I have the CustomerID and the FirstName and LastName of the customer. What I need to do is get only the FirstName and LastName of the Customers who have a recorded PurchaseID of 1 or 2 or 7. When I try my code, I get all the customers from my second tabel (which holds the FirstName, LastName, and CustomerID) and that is not correct.

This is my Code:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
  FROM Customer, Purchase
 WHERE Purchase.PurchaseID = '1'
    OR Purchase.PurchaseID = '2' 
    OR Purchase.PurchaseID = '7'
 GROUP BY FirstName, LastName;
```

I am very new to SQL and would really appreciate the help here.

Comment: What is relationship between Customer, Purchase tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.FirstName, c.LastName
FROM Customer c
JOIN Purchase p ON p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE p.PurchaseID IN ('1', '2', '7')
ORDER BY  c.LastName, c.FirstName
```

**UPDATE**: In response to @David Aldridge comments, I just tested both forms (his and mine) on SQL SERVER 2008 R2 with latest service pack. and they generate **IDENTICAL** cost execution plans. And in fact my join form does a slightly lower number of logical reads (but that may vary with the actual ID's choosen, of course)

I ran these 2 queries against the SQL Server sample database, AdventureWorksDW2008 (since David mentioned that "I've worked on data warehouses"):

```
select distinct c.FirstName, c.LastName
from dbo.FactInternetSales s 
join dbo.DimCustomer c on c.CustomerKey = s.CustomerKey 
where s.ProductKey IN (328, 333, 472)

SELECT FirstName,
       LastName
FROM   dbo.DimCustomer c
where  exists (
       select null
       from   dbo.FactInternetSales s
       WHERE  s.CustomerKey = c.CustomerKey and
              s.ProductKey in (328, 333, 472))
```

Comment: If the purchase record details are not required in the answer then a simple join could be very inefficient, unless the optimiser recognises that excluding purchase columns and including distinct allows the query to halt for each customer when a single matching product has been found. I don't think that it will.

Comment: It surely is, but it's also easy to test whether it actually does the transformation or not. This query could be very inefficient, and I think it's generally better to write a semantically correct query that doesn't rely so much on the optimiser. Sorry, but I've got to vote this down because I've worked on data warehouses where this would be awfully inefficient compared with an exists-based method.

Comment: downvotes are for incorrect answers, not because you don't like them.

Comment: Instead of guessing, I've run a test. Both plans are the same cost.

Comment: There are always many answers to get the same result. Some produce the same plan based on Oracle version (I see that you tested it on SQL Server), init params, data volume, clustering factor etc. The difference is their readability, their efficiency, how well they work across multiple versions, etc.. For Stackoverflow it also matters how well they extend to a more general case. Downvotes encapsulate all of this, and I downvoted based on semantics and possible performance issue. I'm quite happy to be judged based on that -- I'm here to help, not to win anything.

Comment: @David Aldridge: you downvoted incorrectly, as I have demonstrated.

Comment: On Oracle 11.2 the join-based method uses a hash join and sort distinct, whereas the exists uses a single hash semi-join -- a more efficient plan. The costs are similar for SQLFiddle-sized data sets (probably for adventureworks too, which is obviously not representatively sized) because the distinct is run in memory, but that obviously won't extend to larger data volumes. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0bfcd/6

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT C.FirstName, C.LastName
  FROM Customer C
  JOIN Purchase P ON P.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
 WHERE P.PurchaseID IN ('1','2','7')
 GROUP BY C.FirstName, C.LastName
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle test code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab3bd/1) just in case to be sure it works. Added several purchases by same customer to be sure is not repeating on the result. Thanks David Aldridge for pointing that out.

There is another option, using `EXISTS` as on the answer proposed by David. Is should be efectively more efficient if you have big tables to work with. Check this other [SQL Fiddle test code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab3bd/4) with that option.

Avoid using old ANSI-89 JOIN syntax, use JOIN for better readibility:

```
 FROM Customer, Purchase
WHERE Purchase.PurchaseID = '1'
```

Check [Aaron Bertrands blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) for more information about it

Comment: Won't this return one row per customer for every product they have purchased of those types?

Comment: If you add a GROUP BY it should fix any redundant names popping up.

Comment: That wouldn't be semantically correct though. A distinct would be closer, but the query finds the complete list of all the matching products that the customer bought and then essentially discards them. Potentially very inefficient.

Comment: You are correct @DavidAldridge, I corrected both on code and sql fiddle. Tested and indeed it was returning dup values for each customer and all it's purchases. Your `EXISTS` answer should be more efficient indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to basically do Join . What you are attempting to do is old ANSI SQL-89 syntax of JOIN. but this is not recommended .

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Customer, Purchase
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = Purchase.CustomerID
AND ( Purchase.PurchaseID = '1' OR Purchase.PurchaseID = '2' 
OR Purchase.PurchaseID = '7' )
```

The proper way to do is as mentioned in Mitchwheat answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether there exists a purchase of various products for the customer, then use:

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName
FROM   Customer
where  exists (
       select null
       from   Purchase
       WHERE  Purchase.customerID = customer.customerid and
              Purchase.PurchaseID in ('1','2','7'))
```

The optimiser only has to find a single row in the purchase table to know that the customer is to be included.

Comment: Yeap, it works, I don't know why the downvote. Here is a [sql fiddle to test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab3bd/4)

Answer (score -1):

Another way, to go without `IN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.FirstName, c.LastName
FROM Customer c
JOIN Purchase p ON p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE
p.PurchaseID = '1' OR p.PurchaseID = '2' 
OR p.PurchaseID = '7'
ORDER BY  c.LastName, c.FirstName
```